# Проблема с выполнением программы на С

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, подскажите в чем проблема ?Почему не работает программа ?Заранее спасибо)

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
void main()
{
int x,y,e,z;
double a1,a2,a3,a4,a5;       
 printf("Vvedite znavhenie X:\n");
 scanf("%d", &x); 
  printf("Vvedite znavhenie Y:\n");
 scanf("%d", &y);
  printf("Vvedite znavhenie E:\n");
 scanf("%d", &e);
  printf("Vvedite znavhenie Z:\n");
 scanf("%d", &z);
 a1=pow(z,3)*pow(sin(y),2);
 a2=(pow(z,3)/y-pow(z,3))+y;
 a3=a1/a2;
 a4=sqrt(fabs(x)+exp(y))+pow(y,x);
 a5=a4-a3;
 printf("\a\n Answer:  a5=%lf, Press any key...", a5);
 getch( );
}
```

Comment: телепаты в отпуске

Comment: Что значит «не работает»? Не компилируется? Не может найти `#include`? Вылетает из-за неправильных параметров (деление на ноль, корень из отрицательного числа, степень отрицательного числа)? Выдаёт неправильный результат, потому что вы вводите угол в градусах? Не печатает правильный ответ из-за неверного формата в `printf`? Вы бы приложили собственные усилия, вы ж программист?

Comment: В рубрику "люблю такое".

Comment: @LovelyCat если надо на Си, то

      #include <stdio.h>
      #include <math.h>

Вместо getch() -- getchar(), потому как conio.h есть далеко не везде. Возможно потребуется указать библиотеку с мат.функциями. Но это уже зависит от транслятора.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h> // добавил

int main() // void изменил на int
{
int x,y,e,z;
double a1,a2,a3,a4,a5;       
 printf("Vvedite znavhenie X:\n");
 scanf("%d", &x); 
  printf("Vvedite znavhenie Y:\n");
 scanf("%d", &y);
  printf("Vvedite znavhenie E:\n");
 scanf("%d", &e);
  printf("Vvedite znavhenie Z:\n");
 scanf("%d", &z);
 a1=pow(z,3)*pow(sin(y),2);
 a2=(pow(z,3)/y-pow(z,3))+y;
 a3=a1/a2;
 a4=sqrt(fabs(x)+exp(y))+pow(y,x);
 a5=a4-a3;
 printf("\a\n Answer:  a5=%lf, Press any key...", a5);
 getchar(); // getch изменил на getchar. можно вообще удалить
 return 0; // добавил
}
```

Comment: Это не программа на C.

Comment: Если проблема была именно в отсутствующем include <stdio.h>, то IMHO лучше было изменить scanf на cin и printf на cout, чем смешивать Си и С++ код.

Comment: я просто не знаю функции getch. ее можно вообще опустить и запускать программу из под консоли

Comment: поправил. getch изменил на getchar